# Is it possible to link six monitors together

Tags: networking

At the Raspberry Pi Club, we have 6 individual monitors attached together on a screen. Each monitor is connected to a Raspberry Pi, and also linked to the Raspberry Pi's next to each other as well. Is it possible to link these together and separately?

At the moment the Raspberry Pis are linked together using Ethernet into a switch that links them altogether as well as providing them with network access.

**Together**

An example situation would be playing a video across all six screens so that a different part shows on each screen instead of the one video playing across each screen.

Also, is it possible to control other Raspberry Pis from a couple of keyboards so that one keyboard is not needed to be for each screen.

**Separate**

When coding each Raspberry Pi can be connected separately. This works at the moment by disconnecting the cables that connect them together and programming them separately. I was wondering if there was a way of just disconnecting them using the terminal instead of physically removing the cable.

Comment: I am more than willing to clarify more information if needs be please feel free to leave a comment below. Please note that we are ammeters so you may have to go slow if you are a professionakl user.

Comment: 'ammeters' are instruments used to measure electrical current. I believe the word you were looking for was 'amateur'. :)

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve or what your setup is like. Perhaps a couple of pictures would be illuminating?

Comment: Take a look at PiWall, maybe their solution can help you? 
http://www.piwall.co.uk/

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to achieve, where would the best place to find out how to do that would be as what you showed me was a blog post and not instructions